# Migrate Exchange 2007 Mailbox between Servers

Tags: email, exchange, migration, contacts, mailbox

I am using Outlook 2007 and Exchange 2007. I will need to migrate my Exchange mailbox from one server to another (different organizations), including all email, contacts, and calendar.

I have read that there are ways to do this on the server side, but what methods could be used by me to facilitate this on the end-user side?  Is there way to back up my mailbox data so that it could be "imported" into the target mailbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:  use the File->Import/Export feature to export to .pst file, one folder at a time.  Then import on the new mailbox.

The only problem I had was that when I backed up my Inbox and all sub-folders, some messages in sub-folders were not imported on the new mailbox.